# CSS background image placement

Tags: css, background-image

I have this site here http://cowelllaserhair.com/index.php and you will notice that there is a paragraph with a div wrapped around it like so...

```
<div style="background-image:url(/images/newLocation.jpg);">
<p style="text-align:center;">
Text here
</p>
</div>
```

But it cuts off the image and im also looking to have image higher up [like this](http://cowelllaserhair.com/images/newLocation2.jpg)

is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

Solved the issue with the image being cut off by adding the height of the image in my div with the background-image `<div style="background-image:url(/images/newLocation.jpg); height:580px;">`

The only thing now is getting the text inside the image. goto http://cowelllaserhair.com/index.php to see what I am talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to add these two rules:

- `position: relative` to the `div`;
- `position: absolute` to the paragraph.

This way you can easily move the paragraph inside its parent.

Check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyzzy/HDp4v/): I've just applied `top: 100px` to the paragraph, in order to center it vertically inside the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need the 'p' tag.

Simply set the div to be the same width and height as the background image and to be text align center.

Then set some padding to the top of the DIV so that your text is in the position you require (make sure to subtract the amount of top padding you use from the heighyt of the DIV.

Set the background image to have no repeat and be position top, left.

Simples.

```
div {
    width:XXXpx
    height:XXXpx
    padding-top:20px;
    background:url(/images/newLocation.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
    text-align:center;
}

<div>
    Text here
</div>
```